# cvSet2D() called to set the pixel value of an image returns a value of 0

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

When I use `cvSet2D()` to set the pixel value of an image like this:

```
Iplimage* image=cvLoadImage("....");
CvScalar scalar(0.1415, 0, 0, 0);
cvSet2D(image, 0，0，scalar);

double pixelValue=cvGet2D(image, 0, 0).val[0];
```

`pixelValue` turns out to be `0`. Why? Can anybody give me an interpretation?

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with an 8 bit image (3-channel the way you load it, without any flags), which means that for each channel your values are in the range [0, 255]. So even though you assign a `float` value, you can only have `uchar` and thus your 0.1415 becomes 0.

If you had a `float CvMat`, then you could assign `float` values. For example:

```
CvMat* matrix = cvCreateMat(10, 10, CV_32F);
CvScalar scalar(0.1415, 0, 0, 0);
cvSet2D(matrix, 5, 5, scalar);
double pixelValue = cvGet2D(matrix, 5, 5).val[0];  // Now pixelValue = 0.1415
```

If you want to work with `float` images, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394488/how-to-convert-an-8-bit-opencv-iplimage-to-a-32-bit-iplimage) and [this post](http://www.simonsilk.com/content/simonsilk/2011-feb/floating-point-images-opencv).

Comment: And remember, when working with colored images `.val[0]` refers to the blue channel since OpenCV default pixel format is BGR.