# How to convert 8 bit IplImage to 24 bit IplImage in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, iplimage

I have an 8 bit `IplImage` and I want to convert it to a 24 bit `IplImage`. How can I do this?

Comment: I just would like to reccomend you to use C++ API, and use cv::Mat data types. Easier allways.

Comment: 8bit grayscale to 24bit RGB (3x8) or 8bit grayscale to 24bit grayscale(1x24)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your gray image is in a variable called `image` -

```
IplImage *rgbimage = cvCreateImage(/*whatever size*/, 8, 3);
cvCvtColor(image, rgbimage, CV_GRAY2BGR);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need [cvConvertScale](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_BasicFuncs.htm#decl_cvConvertScale) this is an example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394488/how-to-convert-an-8-bit-opencv-iplimage-to-a-32-bit-iplimage)

```
    IplImage *im8 = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
    IplImage *im32 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(im8->width, im8->height), 32, 3);

    cvConvertScale(im8, im32, 1/255.);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go,

```
Mat input_8Bit;
vector <Mat> Vec_temp_8bit;

Vec_temp_8bit.push_back ( input_8Bit );
Vec_temp_8bit.push_back ( input_8Bit );
Vec_temp_8bit.push_back ( input_8Bit );

Mat Output_24Bit;

merge ( Vec_temp_8bit, Output_24Bit );
```

Please give a try, I havent checked it. But logically it should work!

Comment: The cvtColor (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) function does exactly what you described, in one line.