# Issues facing in Opencv cvConvertScale

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing, iplimage

This is very simple code, But don't know where it Went wrong,where i covert Image from 8 to 32

Same thread as like this

[How to convert an 8-bit OpenCV IplImage* to a 32-bit IplImage*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394488/how-to-convert-an-8-bit-opencv-iplimage-to-a-32-bit-iplimage)

```
char * InputImagePath = "E:\\Inp\\lg1.jpg";
IplImage* ImageIn = cvLoadImage(InputImagePath,1);

IplImage *img32 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(ImageIn), 32 , 3);
cvConvertScale(ImageIn,img32,1/255.);

cvSaveImage("E:\\Inp\\zzout.jpg",img32);
```

Output : zzout.jpg is saved in my local hard disk but its empty ( blank image )

Please help me out from this.. fedup with this simple issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you are stuck on the old OpenCV here is a more complete answer:

- 8 bit image - 1 color channel
- 24 bit image - 3 color channels (Blue, Green, Red)
- 32 bit image - 4 color channels (BGR + Alpha - very common in PNGs)

As I can see, Pixel, you are operating on JPEGs which means, you will need to handle either 8 bit (Grayscale) or 24 bit (BGR) input.

Here is the code you need:

```
if (inputImage->nChannels == 1)
{
    cvCvtColor(inputImage, image24bit, CV_GRAY2BGR);
}   
else
{
    cvCopy(inputImage, image24bit, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not bound to use the old-style OpenCV structures, I suggest switching to the more intuitive way of handling images in the newer versions : [ cv::Mat ] and I/O: [ cv:imread / cv:imwrite ]
Give it a read:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: While I agree whole heartedly with the advice, this doesn't address the actual problem at all!  -1 for giving a link to a very old version of the documentation - use http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html

Comment: thank you for pointing to the latest doc. however, I tend to believe that reading about cv::Mat in the original doc is very relevant (i.e. to see full list of methods).

Answer (score 1):

cvSaveImage can only save 8 bit images.

You are trying to save a 32 bit float image as a jpeg, but jpeg only supports 8 bit (ok the standard has 12 bit but nobody supports that).

Comment: Then how to Save 32 bit Image ?

Comment: IS it possible to convert Gray image to color Image ( 24 bit ) ?

Comment: I have used YAML format (see cv::FileStorage). Make it seem to cvSaveImage that our image has 4 times as big - I just repack each 4 byte pixel into 4x 1 byte images. I am not sure how to do this with an IplImage as I normally use a Mat (much easier to use)

Comment: cvCvtColor(grayImage, colorImage, CV_GRAY2BGR) will  convert Gray image to color Image ( 24 bit )